# Polar of revolution cone

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $s\in\mathbb{R}^n, \|s\|=1$ and $\theta\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Consider the cone 
$$
K=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \langle s, x\rangle\geq \|x\|\cos\theta\}.
$$
and 
$$
K^*=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\langle x, y\rangle\leq 0\quad \forall y\in K\}.
$$
Find the closed form of $K^*$

**Guess.** By using geometrical illustration we guess that
$$
K=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \langle -s, x\rangle\geq \|x\|\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta)\}.
$$
But I can not prove this assertion.

I hope someone helps me to give the full solution for this problem.

Comment: what is $y$? in $K^{*}$

Comment: @rlartiga: Thank you for your comments. I revised it.

Comment: One question, the modulo of $s$ have a property?

Comment: I was thinking in your problem, in the definition of $K^*$ is for some $y \in K$ or for all?

Comment: No, $x\in K^*$ if and only if $\langle x, y\rangle\leq 0$ for all $y\in K$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
K^{0}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \langle-s, x\rangle\geq\|x\|\sin\theta\}.
$$
It is easy to check that $K^0$ is a cone, i.e., $\lambda x\in K^0$ for all $\lambda>0$.
We will prove that $K^0=K^*$.

- $K^0\subset K^*$

Let $x_1\in K, x_2\in K^0$. We have
$$ 
\langle s, x_1\rangle\geq\|x_1\|\cos\theta, \quad \langle-s, x_2\rangle\geq\|x_2\|\sin\theta.
$$
It follows that
$$
\|x_1-x_2\|=\|x_1-x_2\|\|s\|\geq\langle s, x_1-x_2\rangle\geq \|x_1\|\cos\theta+\|x_2\|\sin\theta.
$$
Taking the square both sides of the above inequality
$$
\|x_1-x_2\|^2\geq\left(\|x_1\|\cos\left(\theta\right)+\|x_2\|\sin\left(\theta\right)\right)^2.
$$
Expanding and reducing the latter inequality we get
$$
\langle x_1, x_2\rangle \leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\|x_1\|\sin\theta-\|x_2\|\cos\theta\right)^2.
$$
Since $K, K^0$ are cone, it follows that $\langle x_1, x_2\rangle\leq 0$. Hence $K^0\subset K^*$.

- $K^*\subset K^0$

Let $x\in K^*$. We first prove that $s+\frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\in K$. Indeed, we have
$$
\langle s, s+\frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\rangle=1+\langle s, \frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\rangle\geq 1-\sin\theta\geq 0
$$
and
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\langle s, s+\frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\rangle\right)^2&=&\left\|s+\frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\right\|^2\cos\theta^2+\left(\sin\theta+\frac{x}{\|x\|\sin\theta}\right)^2\sin^2\theta.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence 
$$
\langle s, s+\frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\rangle\geq \left\|s+\frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\right\|\cos\theta.
$$
It follows that $s+\frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\in K$. Since $x\in K^*$,
$$
0\geq \langle x, s+\frac{x}{\|x\|}\sin\theta\rangle
$$
or equivalently
$$
\langle-s, x\rangle\geq \|x\|\sin\theta.
$$
Hence $x\in K^0$.